# PHP Code Not working after Upgrading Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I am working on a joomla website. Some developer created a module that displays data on selection of a city. The code was working fine on joomla 1.5 but after upgrading joomla it displays all data without filtering. 
I am just working on solution. I did not code. Here is the code, is there anything deprecated from php 5.3?

```
 // no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access'); 

if(isset($_SESSION['CITY_SELECTION'])){
    $selected_city = $_SESSION['CITY_SELECTION'];
}
else {
    $selected_city = '-SELECT A CITY-';
}

echo "<div id='city_selector'><form name='CITY_SELECTION_FORM' method='get' action='/residential-home.html'>" ;
echo "<SELECT id='city_input' name='CITY_SELECTION' onchange='this.form.submit();'>"; 


echo $selected_city;

foreach ($cities as $city=>$cityname) 
{
    $select = "";   
    if(strtolower(trim($selected_city))==strtolower(trim($cityname)))
    {
         $select = " SELECTED";
    }
    else
    {
        $select = "";
    }
    echo "<OPTION value='".$cityname."'".$select."> ".$cityname."</option>"; 
}

echo '</select>';
echo '</form></div>';
```

mod_cityselection.php

```
// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// Include the syndicate functions only once
require_once (dirname(__FILE__).DS.'helper.php');

$cities = CitySelection::getCities();

require(JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_cityselection'));
```

helper.php

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Direct Access to this location is not allowed.');

class CitySelection
{
    /**
     * Returns a list of cities
    */
    public function getCities()
    {
        // get a reference to the database
        $db = &JFactory::getDBO();

        // get the list of cities in the custom city_selection
        $query = 'SELECT CS.cityname FROM #__city_selection AS CS Order By cityname ASC;';

        $db->setQuery($query);
        $cities = $db->loadResultArray();

        return $cities;
    } //end getCities

} //end CitySelection
```

Comment: The else statement is completely useless, you can just delete it. As for that, nothing else looks wrong without some more details.

Comment: Not related to a php upgrade, but you should escape your values when you output to html as the values could break it: `htmlspecialchars($cityname)`

Comment: And if it is showing too many cities, the problem is located where the cities are retrieved, not here.

Comment: The same code is working on 1.5 Joomla. Somehow it is displaying data for all cities. where i can see the design for this module?

Comment: can you provide the code from the **helper.php** or the **mod_modulename.php** as I believe the issue will be in one of those 2 files

Comment: updated with helper.php and mod_modulename.php

Answer (score 0):

There were several changes in the joomla framework, which require small changes in J1.5-extensions, if you want to use them in latter Joomla versions.

Lots of them are described in the [Joomla Wiki](http://docs.joomla.org/Adapting_a_Joomla_1.5_extension_to_Joomla_2.5). However I assume the problem to be in an other part of the code, maybe in the file that processes the form data.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following for your query in the *helper.php* file which uses Joomla 2.5 coding standards:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();     
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select($db->quoteName('CS.cityname'))
 ->from($db->quoteName('#__city_selection', 'CS'))
 ->order($db->quoteName('cityname') . ' DESC');

$db->setQuery($query);

$cities = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Hope this helps